# YouTube embeds on Blog Overflow

Tags: feature-request, blog

According to Settings->Media, auto-embeds are enabled on the Cooking.SE blog. So, we should be able to embed a YouTube video by just [putting the URL by itself on a line](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), or by using the [[youtube=]](http://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/youtube/) syntax.

However, neither works.

Nor does using the embed code (iframe version) that YouTube will generate for you (it gets stripped out when you save).

Please enable embeds on Cooking. I hear Photo wants it as well, so if you made that settings checkbox actually work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a peek at Arqade's blog, which has been using youTube videos since antiquity, apparently the syntax for embedding youTube videos isn't just a raw link or surround with brackets. Rather, the correct syntax is `[embed]<youTubeURL>[/embed]`. That should work if you use it that way.